# Kivy Screen Manager Can't implement Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I'm trying to do "Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)" so I can join some thread's and close the app smoothly... but I've TRIED and I have no idea how to implement this.

Ive tried so many different variations on of the code, but nothing seems to work... and I can't seem to find an alternative implementation online, like through the .kv file or something... (and I'm dumb...)

Here's my .kv file

```
WindowManager:
    transition: NoTransition()
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:


<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            text: "Go To Next Screen"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    GridLayout:
        id: "Container"
        cols: 2
        rows: 1

        ScrollView:
            id: "SideMenuScrollView"
            size_hint: ("0.3dp", 1)
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False

            StackLayout:
                id: "SideMenuStack"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height

                Button:
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    size: ("92dp", "92dp")

                Button:
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    size: ("92dp", "92dp")


        GridLayout:
            size_hint: (1, 1)
            id: "MyGrid"
            size: (1, 1)
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            cols: 1
            rows: 2

            TextInput:
                id: "text_input"
                multiline: False
                text: ""
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: "30dp"


            Button:
                text: "Do Stuff"
                on_release: root.DoStuff()
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: "70dp"
```

Here's my code

```
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class FirstWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):

    def on_request_close(self):
        SecondWindow.textpopup(title='Close the App?', text='Are you sure?')
        return True

    def DoStuff(self):
        pass


kv = Builder.load_file('new_window.kv')


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I Figured it out... just got more bugs now XD

for anyone wondering, I put

```
    def on_enter(self):
        Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)
```

Inside `class SecondWindow` and it worked! but now I'm getting "in join raise RuntimeError("cannot join current thread")" so... hero...